# How many Include I can use on ObjectSet in EntityFramework to retain performance?

Tags: performance, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2, linq-to-entities

I am using the following LINQ query for my profile page:

```
var userData = from u in db.Users
                        .Include("UserSkills.Skill")
                        .Include("UserIdeas.IdeaThings")
                        .Include("UserInterests.Interest")
                        .Include("UserMessengers.Messenger")
                        .Include("UserFriends.User.UserSkills.Skill")
                        .Include("UserFriends1.User1.UserSkills.Skill")
                        .Include("UserFriends.User.UserIdeas")
                        .Include("UserFriends1.User1.UserIdeas")
                               where u.UserId == userId
                               select u;
```

It has a long object graph and uses many Includes. It is running perfect right now, but when the site has many users, will it impact performance much?

Should I do it in some other way?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

A query with includes returns a single result set and the number of includes affect how big data set is transfered from the database server to the web server. Example:

Suppose we have an entity `Customer (Id, Name, Address)` and an entity `Order (Id, CustomerId, Date)`. Now we want to query a customer with her orders:

```
var customer = context.Customers
                      .Include("Orders")
                      .SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == 1);
```

The resulting data set will have the following structure:

```
 Id | Name | Address | OrderId | CustomerId | Date 
---------------------------------------------------
  1 |  A   |   XYZ   |    1    |     1      | 1.1.
  1 |  A   |   XYZ   |    2    |     1      | 2.1.
```

It means that `Cutomers` data are repeated for each `Order`. Now lets extend the example with another entities - 'OrderLine (Id, OrderId, ProductId, Quantity)`and`Product (Id, Name)`. Now we want to query a customer with her orders, order lines and products:

```
var customer = context.Customers
                      .Include("Orders.OrderLines.Product")
                      .SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == 1);
```

The resulting data set will have the following structure:

```
 Id | Name | Address | OrderId | CustomerId | Date | OrderLineId | LOrderId | LProductId | Quantity | ProductId | ProductName
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 |  A   |   XYZ   |    1    |     1      | 1.1. |     1       |    1     |     1      |    5     |    1      |     AA
  1 |  A   |   XYZ   |    1    |     1      | 1.1. |     2       |    1     |     2      |    2     |    2      |     BB
  1 |  A   |   XYZ   |    2    |     1      | 2.1. |     3       |    2     |     1      |    4     |    1      |     AA
  1 |  A   |   XYZ   |    2    |     1      | 2.1. |     4       |    2     |     3      |    6     |    3      |     CC
```

As you can see data become quite a lot duplicated. Generaly each include to a reference navigation propery (`Product` in the example) will add new columns and each include to a collection navigation property (`Orders` and `OrderLines` in the example) will add new columns and duplicate already created rows for each row in the included collection.

It means that your example can easily have hundreds of columns and thousands of rows which is a lot of data to transfer. The correct approach is creating performance tests and if the result will not satisfy your expectations, you can modify your query and load navigation properties separately by their own queries or by `LoadProperty` method.

Example of separate queries:

```
var customer = context.Customers
                      .Include("Orders")
                      .SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == 1);
var orderLines = context.OrderLines
                        .Include("Product")
                        .Where(l => l.Order.Customer.Id == 1)
                        .ToList();
```

Example of `LoadProperty`:

```
var customer = context.Customers
                      .SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == 1);
context.LoadProperty(customer, c => c.Orders);
```

Also you should always load only data you really need.

**Edit:** I just created [proposal on Data UserVoice](http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2770979-offer-eager-loading-strategies) to support additional eager loading strategy where eager loaded data would be passed in additional result set (created by separate query within the same database roundtrip). If you find this improvement interesting don't forget to vote for the proposal.

Comment: +5 (if I could) I wasn't aware of that and used to work with eager loading rather naively. That's a really good example how much knowledge about the "R" in "ORM" is still necessary to use an ORM effectively - unfortunately...

Answer (score 15):

(You can improve performance of many includes **by creating 2 or more small data request** from data base like below.

According to my experience,Only can give **maximum 2 includes per query** like below.More than that will give really bad performance.

```
var userData = from u in db.Users
                        .Include("UserSkills.Skill")
                        .Include("UserIdeas.IdeaThings")
                        .FirstOrDefault();

 userData = from u in db.Users
                    .Include("UserFriends.User.UserSkills.Skill")
                    .Include("UserFriends1.User1.UserSkills.Skill")
                    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Above will bring small data set from database by using more travels to the database.

Comment: @MikeCole Thanks at least you have benefited of this post.

Comment: Weirdly, you are right, it does work. In my case the combined single query failed to correct sql, but two separate ones work.

Answer (score 8):

Yes it will.  Avoid using Include if it expands multiple detail rows on a master table row.

I believe EF converts the query into one large join instead of several queries.  Therefore, you'll end up duplicating your master table data over every row of the details table.

For example: Master -> Details.  Say, master has 100 rows, Details has 5000 rows (50 for each master).

If you lazy-load the details, you return 100 rows (size: master) + 5000 rows (size: details).

If you use .Include("Details"), you return 5000 rows (size: master + details).  Essentially, the master portion is duplicated over 50 times.

It multiplies upwards if you include multiple tables.

Check the SQL generated by EF.

Comment: +1 I found this myself. It's always better to create a number of smaller queries and execute them separately than it is to run them one by one. But what's good is that by the magic of EF, it automatically builds up the object graph for you. So if you load your users in one query, then load your skills, they'll automatically appear in each other's navigation properties. (I'm assuming this is EF in general as I use Code First).

Comment: @Generic Type Tea, I believe it is general for EF.  In fact, I think they build the navigation properties upon first access...

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you to perform load tests and measure the performance of the site under stress. If you are performing complex queries on each request you may consider caching some results.

Answer (score 3):

**The result of include may change: it depend by the entity that call the include method.**

Like the example proposed from Ladislav Mrnka, suppose that we have an entity

Customer (Id, Name, Address)

that map to this table:

```
Id  |  Name   | Address
-----------------------
C1  |  Paul   |   XYZ
```

and an entity Order (Id, CustomerId, Total)

that map to this table:

```
Id |  CustomerId  | Total
-----------------------
O1 |      C1      |  10.00
O2 |      C1      |  13.00
```

The relation is **one Customer** to **many Orders**

---

**Esample 1: Customer => Orders**

```
var customer = context.Customers
                      .Include("Orders")
                      .SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == "C1");
```

**Linq will be translated in a very complex sql query.**

In this case the query will produce two record and the informations about the customer will be replicated.

```
 Customer.Id   |   Customer.Name |    Order.Id |  Order.Total
-----------------------------------------------------------
     C1        |       Paul      |       O1    |    10.00     
     C1        |       Paul      |       O2    |    13.00
```

---

**Esample 2: Order => Customer**

```
var order = context.Orders
                      .Include("Customers")
                      .SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == "O1");
```

**Linq will be translated in a simple sql Join.**

In this case the query will produce only one record with no duplication of informations:

```
 Order.Id |  Order.Total |  Customer.Id   |   Customer.Name
-----------------------------------------------------------
     O1   |    10.00     |      C1        |       Paul
```