# Preload Entity Framework 4 tree

Tags: entity-framework-4

I would like to preload my catalog in my web application. I'm using EF4 and would like to prefetch all my catalog data. Is there a simple way to do it with EF4 ?

DB structure : 
Catalog -> Category -> [Category ->] product -> options

How can I preload all objects on application start ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply call:

```
var data = context.Catalogs.Include("Categories.Products.Options").ToList();
```

I assume that `Catalog` has navigation property `Categories`, `Category` has navigation property `Products` and `Product` has navigation property `Options`. This will probably [create enormous result set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521749/how-many-include-i-can-use-on-objectset-in-entityframework-to-retain-performance/5522195#5522195).

Pre-loading such big amount of data usually doesn't make any sense. I would say don't do it and load data on demand when you need them. Pre-loading make sense for data which do not change and present almost on every page you show to clients.

Comment: Our Catalog is static and doesn't change during the lifetime of the web application and yes it will create an enormous results set ( yes gigs of data) but it all preloads on application start. I have just read the link that you included very instructive on the .Include part. Now I know not to use the .Include. My original question was how can I preload the Tree and it looks like using .Include is loading a table instead of a tree. How can I preload as a tree ?