# Order child list with entity include get error

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

```
_allTemplates = context.Templates
                       .Include(t => t.Fields.OrderBy(f => f.BaseOrder));
```

and i get this error

> The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property
>   defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation
>   properties and the Select operator for collection navigation
>   properties.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

Include method only specifies the related objects to include in the query results [Include Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

If you need ordering of navigation properties it must be done in some other way. e.g. [How to order child collections of entities in EF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447384/how-to-order-child-collections-of-entities-in-ef) or [EF 4.1 code-first: How to order navigation properties when using Include and/or Select methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522784/ef-4-1-code-first-how-to-order-navigation-properties-when-using-include-and-or)