# EF Core- Sorting a result using Order by clause is not Working

Tags: linq, lambda, entity-framework-6, ef-core-2.0

I am trying to sort my data while using EF Core query expression. However, it is not working for me. I want my data to appear in ascending order. But somehow it is not working. I have used the following query.

```
public Task<Valuation> Execute(GetValuation query, User user)
    {
        return _dbContext.Valuations
            .Where(cre => cre.Id == query.Number)
            .Include(cre => cre.PrimaryValuer)
            .Include(cre => cre.AuthorisingValuer)
            .Include(cre => cre.BuildingDetails)
            .ThenInclude(cre => cre.TenantDetails)
            .OrderBy(cre => cre.BuildingDetails.OrderBy(b => b.DisplayOrder).Where(cc=>cc.TenantDetails!=null).OrderBy(aa => aa.DisplayOrder))
            //.OrderBy(cre => cre.BuildingDetails.Where(cc => cc.TenantDetails != null).OrderBy(aa => aa.DisplayOrder))
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
    }
```

The **BuildingDetails** object contains a property **DisplayOrder** and through this property I am sorting my data using OrderBy. The **DisplayOrder** is an integer which actually contains row index value like 0,1,2, etc. The BuildingDetails also contains a Child object TenantDetails that also has a property **DisplayOrder**.

I am not able to sort my rows in ascending order by using OrderBy even though I have Id as DisplayOrder to sort.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to sort the inner collections? If yes, take a look at [How to order child collections of entities in EF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447384/how-to-order-child-collections-of-entities-in-ef)

Comment: Look into [ThenBy Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.thenby?view=netcore-2.0). Following order expressions should be chained with `ThenBy`, and you also shouldn't use `Where` for checking against `null` values.
If you are checking whether `cc.TenantDetails` is null - and you'd want `nulls` at the end of that sorted list, you could write something like `.OrderBy(cc => cc.TenantDetails != null).ThenBy(cc => cc.DisplayOrder)`. You'd have to combine that with your first `OrderBy`, and at the end you'd ultimately have 1 `OrderBy` and 2 `ThenBy` expressions.