# Entity Framework, performance tuning

Tags: entity-framework, entity, performance

I have entity "Ideas", which has child entity collection "ChildIdeas". I need to load list of ideas and count of "ChildIdeas" (only count!).
I can do:

**eager loading**

```
from i in _dataContext.Ideas.Include("ChildIdeas") ...
```

advantages : all necessary data got by one request;
disadvantages : load unnecessary data. I need only count of ChildIdeas, not full ChildIdeas list

**Explicit loading**

```
from i in _dataContext.Ideas ...

idea.ChildIdeas.Loading()
```

advantages : none;
disadvantages : many requests (ideas.count + 1) instead of one, load unnecessary data

**Independent requests**

```
from i in _dataContext.Ideas ...

_repository.GetCountChildIdeas(idea.ID);
```

advantages : load only necessary data;
disadvantages : many requests (ideas.count + 1) instead of one

all 3 types have disadvantages. Maybe is exist any way to load only necessary data? If yes - what is it, if no - which way is the best for this case?

[ADDED]
after load testing (for 1 user) I got Page Load (in sec):
eager Child Ideas - 1.31 sec
explicit Child Ideas - 1.19 sec
external requests - 1.14 sec

so, eager way for my case is the worst... Why even explicit way is better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use projection. `Count` of child ideas is not part of persisted `Idea` entity so create new non-mapped type containing all properties from `Idea` entity and `Count` property.

```
public class IdeaProjection
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // Other properties
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can use simple projection query to get everything with single request without loading any additional data:

```
var query = from x in context.Ideas
            where ...
            select new IdeaProjection
                {
                    Id = x.Id,
                    // Mapped other properties
                    Count = x.ChildIdeas.Count()
                };
```

Disadvantage is that `IdeaProjection` is not entity and if you want to use it for updates as well you must transform it back to Idea and tell EF about changes. From performance perspective it is best you can get from EF without reverting back to SQL or stored procedures.

Comment: I add your example about eager loading data duplication ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521749/how-many-include-i-can-use-on-objectset-in-entityframework-to-retain-performance/5522195#5522195 ) as possible explanation why OP has measured slower performance with eager than explicite loading.

Comment: No you can't because projection is not possible to mapped class.