# Understanding code first virtual properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

Hi I am just learning to work with Entity Framework Code First and I can not seem to understand something.I have created three models based on a tutorial:

```
public class Course
{
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Credits { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments{ get; set; }
}

public class Enrollment
{
    public int EnrollmentID { get; set; }
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public decimal? Grade { get; set; }
    public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}
public class Student
{
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstMidName { get; set; }
    public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
}
```

My problem is that I do not understand what the properties with virtual do.If I check the database there is no column crate for each of the properties , only for the others.

So what happens when you create a property with the virtual keyword?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It is used to manage **lazy loading** and **change tracking**.

EF will generate proxy types on runtime, which are dynamically generated types that **inherit from your POCO classes** and add all the EF stuff to manage lazy loading / change tracking in the **overridden virtual properties**.

So `virtual` is not a "magic keyword" here, `virtual` is here so your POCOs can be inherited with additional EF-related code at runtime.

Answer (score 7):

Virtual properties are there to allow lazy loading

Answer (score 3):

When you create a property or method marked with the virtual keyword, you will be allowed to override it in a derived class, thus offering your method a more specialized behaviour depending on the objects you create.

In the case of Entity Framework its also a convention that points out that lazy loading behaviour is used. A question regarding this matter exists here: [Entity Framework 4.1 Virtual Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738722/entity-framework-4-1-virtual-properties)

Comment: There's much more to it when working with Entity Framework. It is for example needed by lazy loading mechanism for Entity Framework. See:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738722/entity-framework-4-1-virtual-properties