# How to insert a record into a table with a foreign key using Entity Framework in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first-mapping

I'm new to Entity Framework code-first. This is my learning in ASP.NET MVC, using code-first for database creation.

I have two classes:

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Standard { get; set; }            
    public int SubjectId { get; set; }    

    [ForeignKey("SubjectId")]
    public ICollection<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }
}

public class Subject
{
    [Key]
    public int SubjectId{ get; set; }
    public string SubjectName { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to insert a `Student` record into the `Student` table, which has a foreign key `SubjectId` referencing the `Subject` table.

I'm trying it out in two possible ways:

First approach

```
using(var cxt = new SchoolContext())
{
    Subject sub = new Subject() { SubjectId = 202, SubjectName ="Geology" };
    Student stu = new Student() { Name = "Riya", SubjectId = 202 };
    cxt.Subjects.Add(sub);
    cxt.Students.Add(stu);           

    cxt.SaveChanges();
}
```

Here I created a new `Subject` instance, which has `SubjectId=202`. Now when I create the `Student` object and assign value 202 to `SubjectId`, there is an `Insert` statement conflict. Though there is a `Subject` with `SubjectId = 202`, then why is there an insert conflict? And when I debug, I see that the navigation property `Subjects` is null here. I don't understand the point here.

Second approach:

```
using( var cxt=new SchoolContext())
{
    Student stu = new Student() { Name = "Riya" };
    Subject sub = new Subject() { SubjectId = 202, SubjectName = "Geology" };
    stu.Subjects.Add(sub);
    cxt.Students.Add(stu);               

    cxt.SaveChanges();
}
```

But I get an a null reference exception

> Object Reference not set to instance of an Object

Why is the `stu.Subjects` null here?

So my questions here are:

1. What does the `SubjectId` in `Student` class mean? I.e. what does its value pertain to? Can we explicitly set it, if yes, will it refer to primary key of `Subject` table? If no, is it specified only for EF code conventions purpose?
2. Similarly: what does navigation property role? Why is it null and when it will not be null?

My basic understanding of navigation property is that it is used to make EF determine the relationship between the two entities.

Can anyone please clarify a bit with examples which would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There should be no SubjectId in your Student class. You are probably looking for [many-to-many](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx): a student can have many subjects, a subject can have many students.

Comment: In `Student`, make sure to mark your `Subjects` collection as virtual.

Comment: @Tipx - Virtual is only needed if [lazy loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15247614/understanding-code-first-virtual-properties) is desired. That's not the issue.

Comment: First you need to decide what kind of relation you need, second you need to initialize the foreign key object to be able to insert via a foreign key

Comment: See the student/courses example [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entity-relationships.aspx)

Comment: Can anyone specify me Which of my two approaches is correct?

Comment: Neither of those approaches will work - see my answer

Comment: @SteveGreene `StudentId` is used as primaryKey, Can you clarify me Why you say that `StudentId`  makes no sense?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the SubjectId inside the Student class and the [ForeignKey] attribute on the Subjects collection. See [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) for 1 to many or above for many to many.

Comment: So Is it like if the entity is involved in a relationship having multiplicity greater than one, then no need to specify its primary key as foreign key in other enity. It's navigation property itself will do.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're basically creating a **new** `Student`, and a new `Subject`, in both your approaches. But from what I understand, what you're really trying to do, is create a new `Student`, and assign an **existing** `Subject` (with `SubjectId = 202`) to it - right??

The `SubjectId` in your `Student` class makes absolutely no sense in this setup - since you have a 1:n relationship between `Student` and `Subject`. You need to use that `ICollection<Subject>` to handle the 0:n subjects this student is enrolled in.

For that - use this code:

```
using(var ctx = new SchoolContext())
{
    // create the *NEW* Student
    Student stu = new Student() { Name = "Riya" };

    // get existing subject with Id=202
    Subject sub = ctx.Subjects.FirstOrDefault(s => s.SubjectId == 202);

    // Add this existing subject to the new student's "Subjects" collection
    stu.Subjects.Add(sub);

    // Add the new student to the context, and save it all.
    ctx.Students.Add(stu);           

    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

That will do - a new student will be inserted into your database table, and the 1:n relationship between student and his subjects will be established.

Comment: Can't I do like this, Create a new `Subject`, call `SaveChanges`,next Create `Student` retreive Subject and add this `subject` to the new `Student`