# Why are all my foreign keys null?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I've been playing around with Entity Framework for a while now. For some reason however the foreign keys all seem to be null untill I explicitely use the Include method to include them.

According to what I've read here: 
[Entity Framework 4.1 Virtual Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738722/entity-framework-4-1-virtual-properties)
by making them virtual they should be lazy loaded (and not null).

This is my model:

```
class AltiGoalInfo
{
    public int AltiGoalInfoId { get; set; }
    public int ShotTime { get; set; } //Time it took from shooting till scoring
    public virtual AltiPlayerInfo AltiPlayerInfo { get; set; }
    public virtual AltiTeamEnum Team { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        double shotTime = ShotTime;
        shotTime /= 1000;
        shotTime = Math.Round(shotTime, 2);
        return shotTime + " by " + AltiPlayerInfo;
    }
}



class AltiPlayerInfo
{
    public int AltiPlayerInfoId { get; set; }
    public String VaporId { get; set; }

    public String LastKnownNickname { get; set; }
    public int LastKnownLevel { get; set; }
    public int LastKnownAceRank { get; set; }
    public Boolean LastKnownDemo { get; set; }

    private IList<String> _knownIps = new List<String>();
    public IList<String> KnownIps
    {
        get
        {
            return _knownIps;
        }
        set
        {
            _knownIps = value;
        }
    }

    public string KnownIpsString
    {
        get
        {
            return String.Join(";", _knownIps);
        }
        set
        {
            _knownIps = value.Split(';').ToList();
        }
    }

    public int Goals { get; set; }
    public int MatchesPlayed { get; set; }
    public int MatchesWon { get; set; }

    public double CalcWinRate()
    {
        double mwon = MatchesWon;
        double mplay = MatchesPlayed;
        double result = mwon / mplay * 100.0;
        return Math.Round(result, 0);
    }

    public DateTime FirstSeen { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastSeen { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return LastKnownNickname;
    }
}



class AltiDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<AltiPlayerInfo> AltiPlayerInfos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AltiGoalInfo> AltiGoalInfos { get; set; }
}
```

When I use the following code to acces the data the brrr variable is null:

```
var test = altiDbContext.AltiGoalInfos.First();
var brrr = test.AltiPlayerInfo;
```

When I however include in manually first, it does work:

```
var test = altiDbContext.AltiGoalInfos.Include(t => t.AltiPlayerInfo).First();
var brrr = test.AltiPlayerInfo;
```

Edit:
I've also verified the configuration of the DbContext, by default all settings in the configuration are set to true (which should enable lazy loading).

Comment: Feel free to remove the `Entity Framework` tag from your question title, it's not needed since you've already tagged the question accordingly :)

Comment: I found it a bit more clear since I overlook the tags often too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I had to make the model classes public

Comment: I believe you can also make the classes internal.