# Show data from other model in my View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When I create payment I want to display ClientName in my payment Index View. I get client name from another table called "Clients"

[image]

Payments Model:

```
public class Payments
{
    [Key]
    public int PaymentsId { get; set; }

    public int ClientsId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ClientsId")]
    public virtual Clients Clients { get; set; }
    public String Paymentnumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime PaymentDate { get; set; }
    public Decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public Decimal Discount { get; set; }
    public String Reference { get; set; }
    public String Bank { get; set; }

}
```

Payments controller:

```
// GET: Payments
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.PaymentsList.ToList());
}
```

Payment Index View:

```
@model IEnumerable<localuh.Models.Payments>
....
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Paymentnumber)</th>
    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PaymentDate)</th>
    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Amount)</th>
    <th> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Discount)</th>
    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Reference)</th>
    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Bank)</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Paymentnumber)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PaymentDate)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Amount)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Discount)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Reference)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Bank)</td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.PaymentsId }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.PaymentsId }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.PaymentsId })
    </td>
</tr>
}

</table>
```

So, how can I do that?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I change all suggestions

Comment: Need a break, but can you show the model for `Payment` (it you have set this up correctly, it should have an `int ClientID` property and a `virtual Client Client` property) and I'll have a look in 30 min.

Comment: `Payment` model (the one returned by `db.PaymentsList`), not `PaymentsViewModel`

Comment: Just add another column in your table `<td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Clients.Name)</td>` assuming `Name` is the property of `Clients` that you want to display. Side note: Is confusing that you property is named `Clients` (plural) when it relates to a single Client - suggest you consider renaming

Comment: It works... Can you explain me what virtual does at this case?, it makes an instance of my clients Id or something like that?

Comment: Its used by EF for 'lazy loading' of your related properties - refer the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597760/what-effects-can-the-virtual-keyword-have-in-entity-framework-4-1-poco-code-fi) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738722/entity-framework-4-1-virtual-properties) for a bit more explanation.

Comment: @StephenMuecke  Excelent, I test more deeper and I saw that select value always be my first value of my dropdown, If I select another one and submit it, it post my first value anyway

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean. If you have another issue, then ask another question (and post the relevant code - the GET and POST methods, the associated view and the model used in the view)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Payments` model contains a `virtual` property for `Clients` (which will be 'lazy loaded' by EF, so you simply need to add another table column to display the name of the client. Assuming your `Clients` model has a property `public string Name { get; set; }`, then it would be

```
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Clients.Name)</td>
```

Side note: Suggest you rename the property to `Client`, not `Clients` which suggests its a collection.