# How to chain async calls in a complex linq query

Tags: c#, linq, async-await, entity-framework-core

In a .NET application, I am trying to construct a DTO on the repo layer as following. However, I have a nasty async function deep down in the statement. How should I chain the async calls?

```
var subtopics; // I have a subtopics array

var topicModel = new TopicModel
{
    Id = 0,
    SubtopicModels = subtopics
        .Select(subtopic => new SubtopicModel
        {
            Id = 0,
            VideoModels = subtopic.Videos // simple await on this line doesn't work
                .OrderBy(video => video.OrderInSubtopic)
                .Select(async video => new VideoModel
                {
                    Id = 0,
                    VideoLeftAtSeconds = (await _db.VideoActivities
                        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(activity => activity.UserId == userId && activity.VideoId == videoId))
                        .LeftAtSeconds
                }).ToList()
        }).ToList(),
};
```

Comment: is this all enitty framework core? where does subtopics come from?

Comment: @DanielA.White it doesn't matter where the subtopics are coming from. I excluded all irrelevant codes. I have a subtopics array before this code section

Comment: Sorry, but what you are doing is awful. If you will have 20 items in suptopic.Videos collection, you will create 20 queries to the DB which will impact performance.

Comment: @dantey89 what should I do then? I want to know what you think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the lambda given to the deepest `Select` (`.Select(async video => ...`) is going to return a `Task<T>` (I assume `Task<int>` but not sure from the context).

Select doesn't understand how to use a `Task` and will just pass it through as is. You can convert these in bulk by using `WhenAll` ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51964200/12564275)) but you would have to make extra provisions on the database connection, as this will execute multiple queries in parallel. ([2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10478693/multipleactiveresultsets-in-entity-framework-4-1-code-first))

The most simple way in this instance is probably to scrap the LINQ and use `foreach`, like this:

```
var subtopics;

var topicModel = new TopicModel
{
    Id = 0,
    SubtopicModels = new List<SubtopicModel>()
};

foreach(var subtopic in subtopics)
{
    var subtopicModel = new SubtopicModel
    {
        Id = 0,
        VideoModels = new List<VideoModel>()
    };

    foreach(var video in subtopic.Videos.OrderBy(video => video.OrderInSubtopic))
    {
        subtopicModel.VideoModels.Add(new VideoModel
        {
            Id = 0,
            VideoLeftAtSeconds = (await _db.VideoActivities
                        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(activity => activity.UserId == userId && activity.VideoId == videoId))
                        .LeftAtSeconds
        });
    }

    topicModel.SubtopicModel.Add(subtopicModel);
}
```