# Entity Framework: Many-to-Many .Include() not working

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have the following table structure:

[image: Entity Framework model]

That is, a Supplier has a many-to-many relationship with People (of Person).

> Supplier 1--* SupplierPerson *--1 Person

A Person has a one-to-many relationship with EmaiLAddresses, TelephoneNumbers and WebResources.

> Person 1--* EmailAddress
>   Person 1--* TelephoneNumber
>   Person 1--* WebResource

I've highlighted the navigation properties.

Given the LINQ-to-Entities using .Include() to load the dependencies and shape the result-set:

```
    ObjectQuery<Supplier> supplierQuery=((SopEntities)Context).Suppliers
                .Include("People")
                .Include("People.TelephoneNumbers")
                .Include("People.EmailAddresses")
                .Include("People.WebResources");
#if TRACE
            Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("GetAll(): {0}", supplierQuery.ToTraceString()));
#endif
            return supplierQuery;
```

I get the insanely large and rather useless SQL:

```
SELECT 
[Project5].[ID] AS [ID], 
[Project5].[Key] AS [Key], 
[Project5].[CompanyName] AS [CompanyName], 
[Project5].[AddressLine1] AS [AddressLine1], 
[Project5].[AddressLine2] AS [AddressLine2], 
[Project5].[TownCity] AS [TownCity], 
[Project5].[CountyState] AS [CountyState], 
[Project5].[Postcode] AS [Postcode], 
[Project5].[Country] AS [Country], 
[Project5].[C25] AS [C1], 
[Project5].[C2] AS [C2], 
[Project5].[C3] AS [C3], 
[Project5].[C4] AS [C4], 
[Project5].[C5] AS [C5], 
[Project5].[C6] AS [C6], 
[Project5].[C7] AS [C7], 
[Project5].[C8] AS [C8], 
[Project5].[C9] AS [C9], 
[Project5].[C10] AS [C10], 
[Project5].[C11] AS [C11], 
[Project5].[C1] AS [C12], 
[Project5].[C12] AS [C13], 
[Project5].[C13] AS [C14], 
[Project5].[C14] AS [C15], 
[Project5].[C15] AS [C16], 
[Project5].[C16] AS [C17], 
[Project5].[C17] AS [C18], 
[Project5].[C18] AS [C19], 
[Project5].[C19] AS [C20], 
[Project5].[C20] AS [C21], 
[Project5].[C21] AS [C22], 
[Project5].[C22] AS [C23], 
[Project5].[C23] AS [C24], 
[Project5].[C24] AS [C25]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [Extent1].[Key] AS [Key], 
    [Extent1].[CompanyName] AS [CompanyName], 
    [Extent1].[AddressLine1] AS [AddressLine1], 
    [Extent1].[AddressLine2] AS [AddressLine2], 
    [Extent1].[TownCity] AS [TownCity], 
    [Extent1].[CountyState] AS [CountyState], 
    [Extent1].[Postcode] AS [Postcode], 
    [Extent1].[Country] AS [Country], 
    [UnionAll2].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [UnionAll2].[C2] AS [C2], 
    [UnionAll2].[C3] AS [C3], 
    [UnionAll2].[C4] AS [C4], 
    [UnionAll2].[C5] AS [C5], 
    [UnionAll2].[C6] AS [C6], 
    [UnionAll2].[C7] AS [C7], 
    [UnionAll2].[C8] AS [C8], 
    [UnionAll2].[C9] AS [C9], 
    [UnionAll2].[C10] AS [C10], 
    [UnionAll2].[C11] AS [C11], 
    [UnionAll2].[C12] AS [C12], 
    [UnionAll2].[C13] AS [C13], 
    [UnionAll2].[C14] AS [C14], 
    [UnionAll2].[C15] AS [C15], 
    [UnionAll2].[C16] AS [C16], 
    [UnionAll2].[C17] AS [C17], 
    [UnionAll2].[C18] AS [C18], 
    [UnionAll2].[C19] AS [C19], 
    [UnionAll2].[C20] AS [C20], 
    [UnionAll2].[C21] AS [C21], 
    [UnionAll2].[C22] AS [C22], 
    [UnionAll2].[C23] AS [C23], 
    [UnionAll2].[C24] AS [C24], 
    CASE WHEN ([UnionAll2].[C2] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C25]
    FROM  [dbo].[Supplier] AS [Extent1]
    OUTER APPLY  (SELECT 
        [UnionAll1].[C1] AS [C1], 
        [UnionAll1].[PersonID] AS [C2], 
        [UnionAll1].[SupplierID] AS [C3], 
        [UnionAll1].[SupplierID1] AS [C4], 
        [UnionAll1].[ID] AS [C5], 
        [UnionAll1].[Title] AS [C6], 
        [UnionAll1].[FirstName] AS [C7], 
        [UnionAll1].[Initials] AS [C8], 
        [UnionAll1].[LastName] AS [C9], 
        [UnionAll1].[Position] AS [C10], 
        [UnionAll1].[DepartmentID] AS [C11], 
        [UnionAll1].[ID1] AS [C12], 
        [UnionAll1].[Number] AS [C13], 
        [UnionAll1].[Name] AS [C14], 
        [UnionAll1].[PersonID1] AS [C15], 
        [UnionAll1].[TelephoneNumberTypeID] AS [C16], 
        [UnionAll1].[C2] AS [C17], 
        [UnionAll1].[C3] AS [C18], 
        [UnionAll1].[C4] AS [C19], 
        [UnionAll1].[C5] AS [C20], 
        [UnionAll1].[C6] AS [C21], 
        [UnionAll1].[C7] AS [C22], 
        [UnionAll1].[C8] AS [C23], 
        [UnionAll1].[C9] AS [C24]
        FROM  (SELECT 
            CASE WHEN ([Extent4].[ID] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1], 
            [Extent2].[PersonID] AS [PersonID], 
            [Extent2].[SupplierID] AS [SupplierID], 
            [Extent2].[SupplierID] AS [SupplierID1], 
            [Extent3].[ID] AS [ID], 
            [Extent3].[Title] AS [Title], 
            [Extent3].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
            [Extent3].[Initials] AS [Initials], 
            [Extent3].[LastName] AS [LastName], 
            [Extent3].[Position] AS [Position], 
            [Extent3].[DepartmentID] AS [DepartmentID], 
            [Extent4].[ID] AS [ID1], 
            [Extent4].[Number] AS [Number], 
            [Extent4].[Name] AS [Name], 
            [Extent4].[PersonID] AS [PersonID1], 
            [Extent4].[TelephoneNumberTypeID] AS [TelephoneNumberTypeID], 
            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C2], 
            CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C3], 
            CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C4], 
            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C5], 
            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C6], 
            CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C7], 
            CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C8], 
            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C9]
            FROM   [dbo].[SupplierPerson] AS [Extent2]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[Person] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent3].[ID] = [Extent2].[PersonID]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[TelephoneNumber] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent3].[ID] = [Extent4].[PersonID]
            WHERE [Extent1].[ID] = [Extent2].[SupplierID]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            2 AS [C1], 
            [Extent5].[PersonID] AS [PersonID], 
            [Extent5].[SupplierID] AS [SupplierID], 
            [Extent5].[SupplierID] AS [SupplierID1], 
            [Extent6].[ID] AS [ID], 
            [Extent6].[Title] AS [Title], 
            [Extent6].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
            [Extent6].[Initials] AS [Initials], 
            [Extent6].[LastName] AS [LastName], 
            [Extent6].[Position] AS [Position], 
            [Extent6].[DepartmentID] AS [DepartmentID], 
            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C2], 
            CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C3], 
            CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C4], 
            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C5], 
            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C6], 
            [Extent7].[ID] AS [ID1], 
            [Extent7].[Email] AS [Email], 
            [Extent7].[Name] AS [Name], 
            [Extent7].[PersonID] AS [PersonID1], 
            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C7], 
            CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C8], 
            CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C9], 
            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C10]
            FROM   [dbo].[SupplierPerson] AS [Extent5]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[Person] AS [Extent6] ON [Extent6].[ID] = [Extent5].[PersonID]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[EmailAddress] AS [Extent7] ON [Extent6].[ID] = [Extent7].[PersonID]
            WHERE [Extent1].[ID] = [Extent5].[SupplierID]) AS [UnionAll1]
    UNION ALL
        SELECT 
        3 AS [C1], 
        [Extent8].[PersonID] AS [PersonID], 
        [Extent8].[SupplierID] AS [SupplierID], 
        [Extent8].[SupplierID] AS [SupplierID1], 
        [Extent9].[ID] AS [ID], 
        [Extent9].[Title] AS [Title], 
        [Extent9].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
        [Extent9].[Initials] AS [Initials], 
        [Extent9].[LastName] AS [LastName], 
        [Extent9].[Position] AS [Position], 
        [Extent9].[DepartmentID] AS [DepartmentID], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C2], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C3], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C4], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C5], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C6], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C7], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C8], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C9], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C10], 
        [Extent10].[ID] AS [ID1], 
        [Extent10].[Url] AS [Url], 
        [Extent10].[Name] AS [Name], 
        [Extent10].[PersonID] AS [PersonID1]
        FROM   [dbo].[SupplierPerson] AS [Extent8]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Person] AS [Extent9] ON [Extent9].[ID] = [Extent8].[PersonID]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[WebResource] AS [Extent10] ON [Extent9].[ID] = [Extent10].[PersonID]
        WHERE [Extent1].[ID] = [Extent8].[SupplierID]) AS [UnionAll2]
)  AS [Project5]
ORDER BY [Project5].[ID] ASC, [Project5].[C25] ASC, [Project5].[C2] ASC, [Project5].[C3] ASC, [Project5].[C5] ASC, [Project5].[C1] ASC
```

Which populates the Supplier with People, but not the TelephoneNumbers, EmailAddresses or WebResources.

When executed in SQL Management Studio, I get the incomplete record set:

[image: screenshot of SQL result]

Clearly, the .Include() is not working due to my misunderstanding of its capabilities.

I really would like to avoid having to call the People schema seperately. How can I have this generate useful SQL?

Comment: It will not generate any better SQL. This is how SQL generated by EF looks like (especially when you are [using Include](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521749/how-many-include-i-can-use-on-objectset-in-entityframework-to-retain-performance/5522195#5522195)). The query itself looks like it is querying all you need so the problem is either in your mapping or in your data. You can try to remove first `Include` because include to `People` is in your following Includes as well.

Comment: Thanks Ladislav. I did try to remove .Include("People"), as you're right, it is already referenced. There was no difference, however. I don't expect the SQL to be pretty, I'm not too bothered about it. It's just here for completeness, really. I just want my child collections to be populated. :)

Comment: Ok, I think I found the issue after having pushed some different data through it. And it is nothing to do with the question. The .Include() IS working. So, suggestions welcome. Keep the post up or delete it?

Comment: Answer your own question. It can help others.

Comment: I thought of that, but the answer is nothing to do with the question. ie. it's another problem I have yet to identify the cause of.

Comment: Actually, I will answer it, when I resolve the issue. You're right about it helping others. I'll make it clear in my answer that the two are not necassarily related.

Comment: @Program.X I know that this question is quite old, but I would like to hear about your solution. I have a similar problem, and by now I DO think that it has something to do with the .Include() - because I do not know better. What version of EF/.NET are you talking about here?

Comment: @Marcel: Unfortunately, this was asked in a previous life so I can't give you any feedback as it has left my tiny brain. I think it would have been EF 3.5 looking at the screenshot and considering my reticence to use anything v1 from Microsoft.