# Filter in EF Include

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I have this LINQ query that gives an error on the filter in the Include. 
When searching my friend Google I've found that it's not possible to filter in an Include. I've found some ways to do this on an onther way but I can't get it to work for my specific case.

```
return context.Timesheets.Where(t => t.UserId == userId && t.SubjectDate == date && t.WorkingDaySchedules.Count() > 0)
    .Include(t => t.Project)
    .Select(t => t.Project)
        .Include(p => p.Account)
        .Include(pc => pc.ProjectConsultants.Where(c => c.UserId == userId));
```

It's the last Include that gives me a headache :)
Anyone an idea how to do it?

Comment: You can load the data up in a separate query and the context will join the data up. Also I don't think there is any point including Project than selecting Project that include is redundant.

Comment: One of the more common questions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16798796/ef-include-with-where-clause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things I think need improving here.

---

### **Includes are not meant for filtering**.

It's simply not the correct place to do so.

`Include` is meant to **automatically retrieve all linked entities**. Since you don't want *all* of the entities (you only want a subset), you shouldn't be using an `Include`.
Alternatively, you could still use an `Include`, so long as you're happy to remove the unwanted entries **in memory** (i.e. after they've been loaded). But I assume you don't want that.

Instead, you could use an explicit `Select` statement. As a simple example:

```
context.Projects
             .Where(p => p.Id == projectId)
             .Select(p => new ConsultantSearchResult() {
                   Project = p,
                   ConsultantsNamedBob = p.Consultants.Where(c => c.FirstName == "Bob")
              }).ToList();
```

**Notice the absence of the `Include`**. As I said before, `Include` is used for *automatically* (and implicitly) loading the related data. But because you *explicitly* stated the data you want in the `Select`, there's no need for an implicit inclusion anymore. EF will give you exactly what you ask for.

---

### Your `Select` is unintuitive

I think you're expecting something different than what you're getting. Looking at the code:

```
return context.Timesheets    //1
    .Where(...)              //2
    .Select(t => t.Project)  //3
```

Look at what happens:

1. You select all timesheets.
2. You filter the timesheets and are left with a subset of timesheets
3. You get a list of the projects **of each timesheet**.

If your filtering (step 2) leaves you with **multiple** timesheets from the same project, then `.Select(t => t.Project)` will give you **multiple** instances of the same project. And that's not good.

There are two exceptions here:

- You **know** that you are going to find one timesheet in total. But then you should be using `First`, `Single`, `FirstOrDefault` or `SingleOrDefault`. You should only use `Where` if it's possible that you get more than one result.
- You expect more than one timesheet, but you **know** that you'll never find two timesheets from the same project (thus never creating duplicates when you call the `Select`). I would assume (by reading the entity names) that it's possible for a specific consultant to have multiple timesheets for the same project, but maybe that's not true.

  - If my inference is correct, then you will experience the problem with duplicate projects after you do the `Select`.
  - If my inference is not correct, then I would expect a much stronger relationship between timesheets and consultant, as every project consultant would have exactly 1 (or no) timesheet, never more than 1. But your current data structure lacks any real relationship between timesheets and consultants.

A quick solution would be to use `Distinct`:

```
return context.Timesheets    
    .Where(...)              
    .Select(t => t.Project)  
    .Distinct()
```

But I personally think that a better solution would be to invert the lookup: start with projects, filter *the projects* on their timesheets (rather than filtering the timesheets):

```
return context.Projects    
    .Include(p => p.Timesheets)  
    .Where(p => p.Timesheets.Any(t => t.UserId == userId && ...))              
    .ToList();
```

This precludes the issue with the duplicate projects. Note that this doesn't yet solve your "filtered Include" problem.

---

### Separate queries in the same context

This was also mentioned in the comments. This is a viable option, but I find it a dirty approach that is going to create unintuitive code down the line.

[A simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11917926/loading-related-entities-in-separate-queries-and-sorting-of-children-collection):

```
context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
var parent = context.Set<Entity>().First(e => e.Name = "ABC");
// Load relations in separate query
context.Set<Child>()
       .Where(c => c.Parent.Name == "ABC")
       .OrderBy(c => c.Name) // You can at least try it but as mentioned above it may not work in all scenarios
       .Load();
// Now parent.Children collection should be filled
```

The example uses `OrderBy` instead of `Where`, but both will work the same way.

Even though you queried the children and the parent separately, their navigational properties will continuously be updated because you're running your queries in the same context.

It's a viable option for you, but I'm a bit apprehensive of this code, as it is in no way **readable** that the second query alters the result of the first query.
To me, this feels equally dirty to e.g. having business logic in the `get` or `set` of a property. It works, but it leads to unexpected behavior and will make debugging really difficult.

Note that it may be clear *to you* what is happening behind the scenes, but it's easy for a different developer to gloss over it when looking at the code.

I personally don't like this, but your opinion may differ.

---

### Your incomplete data structure is making it complicated.

Looking at your code sample, I think there's a bit of an issue with your data consistency. You are using the `userId` filter in two places:

- Timesheet: `t => t.UserId == userId`
- Consultant: `c => c.UserId == userId`

If timesheets are connected to a consultant, then there should be a relationship between these two entities. As it currently stands, your project has a list of timesheets and a list of consultants, with no discernible relationship between timesheets and consultant.
**This is why your lookup is co complicated**. You're trying to mock a relationship that isn't there.

If the relationship did exist, it would be much easier to look everything up:

```
return context.Timesheets
                   .Include(t => t.Project)
                   .Include(t => t.Project.Account)
                   .Include(t => t.Consultant)
                   .Where(t => t.Consultant.UserId == userId && t.SubjectDate == date && t.WorkingDaySchedules.Count() > 0)
                   .ToList()
```

And then you get what you're looking for. You no longer have to do two separate `userId` checks, you're no longer required to "manually synchronize" the fake relationship, the lookup process is much more streamlined and readable.

---

### Minor comment

Maybe something you didn't know yet. You can rewrite

```
t.WorkingDaySchedules.Count() > 0
```

as

```
t.WorkingDaySchedules.Any() //is there at least one item in the collection?
```

With the added benefit that you can add filters if you need to:

```
t.WorkingDaySchedules.Any(wds => wds.IsActive)  //is there at least one item in the collection that meets the condition?
```

Answer (score 0):

There is two way to filter include Entity.

- Using a projection (See @Flater answer)
- Using a third party library

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Plus](http://entityframework-plus.net/)

The EF+ Query IncludeFilter allow easily filter included entities.

```
return context.Timesheets.Where(t => t.UserId == userId && t.SubjectDate == date && t.WorkingDaySchedules.Count() > 0)
    .Include(t => t.Project)
    .Select(t => t.Project)
        .IncludeFilter(p => p.Account)
        .IncludeFilter(pc => pc.ProjectConsultants.Where(c => c.UserId == userId));
```

Under the hood, the library does exactly a projection.

One limitation is all `Include` but now be called with `IncludeFilter` even if no filter is specified such as the account.

Wiki: [EF+ Query Include Filter](http://entityframework-plus.net/query-include-filter)